# How to get Web Session from cookie?

Tags: .net, vb.net, session, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to do an scrape a web page but in order to Post the data I need a web session ID like

> web_session=HQJ3G1GPAAHRZGFR

How can I get that ID?

My code so far is:

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim postData As String = "web_session=HQJ3G1GPAAHRZGFR&intext=O&term_code=201210&search_type=A&keyword=&kw_scope=all&kw_opt=all&subj_code=BIO&crse_numb=205&campus=*&instructor=*&instr_session=*&attr_type=*&mon=on&tue=on&wed=on&thu=on&fri=on&sat=on&sun=on&avail_flag=on" '/BANPROD/pkgyc_yccsweb.P_Results 
    Dim tempCookie As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
    Try

        tempCookie.GetCookies(New Uri("https://taylor.yc.edu/BANPROD/pkgyc_yccsweb.P_Results"))
        'postData="web_session=" & tempCookie.

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://taylor.yc.edu/BANPROD/pkgyc_yccsweb.P_Results"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookie
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; Media Center PC 4.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookie.Add(postresponse.Cookies)

        Dim postresreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream)
        Dim thepage As String = postresreader.ReadToEnd
        MsgBox(thepage)
    Catch ex As WebException
        MsgBox(ex.Status.ToString & vbNewLine & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tempCookie.GetCookies()` isn't doing what you think its doing. What it actually does is essentially filter a pre-existing `CookieCollection` down to only include cookies for the supplied URL. Instead, what you need to do is first create a request to a page that will give you this session token, then make the actual request for your data. So first request the page at `P_Search`, then re-use that request with the `CookieContainer` bound to it and post to `P_Results`.

Instead of the `HttpWebRequest` object, however, let me point you to the `WebClient` class and [my post here about extending it to support cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies). You'll find that you can simplify your code a lot. Below is a full working VB2010 WinForms app that shows this. If you still want to use the `HttpWebRequest` object this should at least give you an idea of what needs to be done, too:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//Create our webclient
        Using WC As New CookieAwareWebClient()
            ''//Set SSLv3
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
            ''//Create a session, ignore what is returned
            WC.DownloadString("https://taylor.yc.edu/BANPROD/pkgyc_yccsweb.P_Search")
            ''//POST our actual data and get the results
            Dim S = WC.UploadString("https://taylor.yc.edu/BANPROD/pkgyc_yccsweb.P_Results", "POST", "term_code=201130&search_type=K&keyword=math")
            Trace.WriteLine(S)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CookieAwareWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    Private cc As New CookieContainer()
    Private lastPage As String

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim R = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        If TypeOf R Is HttpWebRequest Then
            With DirectCast(R, HttpWebRequest)
                .CookieContainer = cc
                If Not lastPage Is Nothing Then
                    .Referer = lastPage
                End If
            End With
        End If
        lastPage = address.ToString()
        Return R
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: That was great. I was trying to figure that out forever and could never get it right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I need to support this type of feature in a concurrent environment.  I know WebClient doesn't support concurrent i/o, but is there a way to provide one `CookieContainer` to multiple web requests so that they all use a single session?  Can explain logic more if needed.